# regular expression does not work with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I have a regular expression that works on regexplib.com when I test it with the .NET engine.  It does not find a match with JavaScript.  I have also tried JSFiddle with the below code.  It does not find a match.  It returns null.

```
var re = RegExp('^\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?$');
var myString = "123";
alert(myString.match(re));
```

I am trying to use the below javascript in an aspx web page.  It does not find any matches.  I am open to ideas.

```
function ValidateData(ControlObj, ColumnType) {
var re = new RegExp('^\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?$');

if (!ControlObj.value.match(re)) {
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Better use regex literal instead of regex object:

```
var re = /^\d+(?:\.\d?)?$/;
var myString = "123";
alert(myString.match(re));
```

**Unless until you're building a regular expression dynamically there is no need to use `RegExp` object.**

Otherwise `RegExp` object needs double escaping like:

```
var re = RegExp('^\\d+(?:\\.\\d?)?$');
```

**Reason** for double escaping is that `RegExp` object takes a string as input and escaping is needed first for string and second for the regex engine.

btw `\d{0,1}` can be replaced by `\d?`

Comment: Please explain why the double-escape is necessary.  If not, I will add it later.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I added some explanation.

Comment: It is not true that *\d{0,1} can be replaced by \d**. `\d{0,1}` is the same as `\d?` as `?` means "0 or 1, greedy". See my post.

Answer (score 3):

Use double escaped slashes:

```
var re = RegExp('^\\d+(?:\\.\\d{0,1})?$');
```

And it should work.

In JavaScript, you can use literal notation and a constructor. In literal notation (see anubhava's suggestion), you need to add `/ ... /` and then you do not need to escape slashes. When using a `RegExp` object (a constructor), you must escape backslashes.

Constructor is good when you need to pass variables to your pattern. In other cases, a literal notation is preferrable.

```
var re = /^\d+(?:\.\d?)?$/;
```

`\d{0,1}` is the same as `\d?` as `?` means `0 or 1, greedy`.

See [more about that difference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

> The literal notation provides compilation of the regular expression
>   when the expression is evaluated. Use literal notation when the
>   regular expression will remain constant. For example, if you use
>   literal notation to construct a regular expression used in a loop, the
>   regular expression won't be recompiled on each iteration.
>
> The constructor of the regular expression object, for example, new
>   RegExp('ab+c'), provides runtime compilation of the regular
>   expression. Use the constructor function when you know the regular
>   expression pattern will be changing, or you don't know the pattern and
>   are getting it from another source, such as user input.
>
> When using the constructor function, the normal string escape rules
>   (preceding special characters with \ when included in a string) are
>   necessary.